# python 小数演算について

Tags: python

```
a = 0.9
b = 1-a
c = 1+a
d = 1-0.9

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

この時の結果が次になります。

```
0.9
0.09999999999999998
1.9
```

なぜb=0.1とならないのでしょうか？
初歩的な質問かもしれませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `b = 1-b` は `b = 1-a` の間違いではありませんか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。その通りですね、失礼しました。ただいま編集させていただきました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

丸め誤差ですね。このページを読んでみてください。

[Python チュートリアル - 15. 浮動小数点演算、その問題と制限](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。とても勉強になりました。